# MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(AuthenticationCallback, System.Net.Http.HttpClient)'

Tags: csproj

I have a cs project that uses the new csproj format (Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk") and targets .NET framework 4.6.2, when referencing it from a console application that also uses the new csproj format and targets .NET framework 4.6.2, it works fine, but when referencing it from a WPF application that uses the old csproj format but also targets .NET framework 4.6.2, I get the following exception: MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(AuthenticationCallback, System.Net.Http.HttpClient)' Any suggestion why?